# Run X number of test case per batch on groovy scipt SoapUI

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have this code which runs all test case inside the test suite concurrently:

```
import com.eviware.soapui.model.testsuite.TestSuite.TestSuiteRunType

log.info testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getRunType()
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.setRunType(TestSuiteRunType.PARALLEL)
assert testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getRunType() == TestSuiteRunType.PARALLEL
```

but it seems that the application can't handle too much test case, question is: Is it possible to run test case per batch? like for example I have 300 test cases and it will get only 10 test cases to run concurrently and after it was completed another batch of 10 will be executed?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: What do you mean by scripts? You mean `test cases`?

Comment: yes, Test Case. sorry

Comment: Would you please tell more about the number of suites in the project; and the approximate number of test cases as well?

Comment: I Have 1 test suites which has 300 testcases and I wanted to run the testcases by batch ex: 10 scripts at a time

Comment: Are all the test cases in a single suite?

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar. I use the `Lists.partition` feature of Google Guava (which comes as a soapUI library) to partition the test cases into batches and then I loop through the test cases in each batch and run them. You can add you own logic about what action to take at the end of each batch:

```
import com.google.common.collect.*;

// Get a list of the test cases in the suite and partition them into batches of 10 using Google Guava
def testCases = context.getTestSuite().getTestCaseList();
def List<List<com.eviware.soapui.model.testsuite.TestCase>> testcasePartitions = Lists.partition(testCases, 10);

// Loop through the partitions
for (partition in testcasePartitions) {

    // Loop through the test cases in each partition
    for (testcase in partition) {

        if (!testcase.isDisabled()) {
            log.info("Running tests case " + testcase.getName());           

            def properties = new com.eviware.soapui.support.types.StringToObjectMap ()
            testcase.run(properties, false)         

            // Check the outcomes here if required.
        }
    }
}
```

Because I do this in just one test suite, I've created this as a setup script at the test suite level, which I kick off manually.

Comment: Hi @craigcaulfield, I am having a problem with where I'm gonna put this? I am using SoapUI and it's not possible to put scripts on Suite Level.

Comment: I found a solution to put it into TestStep Level, but I'm having a problem running the 10 scripts per batch concurrently

Comment: You can run it as a set up script at the test suite level. Just double-click on a test suite and along the bottom you'll see a series of tabs, one of which which be Setup Script. Put the script there and run it from there too.

Comment: Does it run concurrentyly on your end?